# Keyboard control of 1d and 2d sliders in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, keyboard

I would like to be able to control the sliders in Manipulate via keyboard control (not just by dragging with the mouse).

How can I do this?

I've seen [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27706/manipulate-slider-over-discrete-collection-keyboard-control), but unfortunately the keyboard part of the question was not answered (the only code having to do with keyboard control gives "recursion errors" when I put it into Mathematica 11).

Comment: There's a fundamental problem:  Suppose your `Manipulate` has several sliders.  How would the software "know" which slider your buttons were controlling?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not currently implemented in Mathematica

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Standard approaches to providing keyboard shortcuts to GUI interfaces include using the Tab key to change focus.